# Is it possible to find a control without using loop?

Tags: vb.net, declare

I have many buttons with different text in a `FlowLayoutPanel`, and I want to find the button with particular string.

I'm currently doing it this way:

```
Dim str as String = 'some text
For each btn as Button in FlowLayoutPanel.Controls
    If btn.Text = str then
         'do something with btn
    End If
Next
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

```
Dim str as String = 'some text
Dim btn as Button = FlowLayoutPanel.Controls.Button.Text with that string
'do something with btn
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LINQ, e.g.

```
Dim btn = myFlowLayoutPanel.Controls.
                            OfType(Of Button)().
                            FirstOrDefault(Function(b) b.Text = myText)
```

Note that that code will work whether all the child controls are `Buttons` or not, as `OfType` ensures that anything but a `Button` is ignored.  If you know that every child control is a `Button` though, it would be more efficient to do this:

```
Dim btn = myFlowLayoutPanel.Controls.
                            Cast(Of Button)().
                            FirstOrDefault(Function(b) b.Text = myText)
```

and more efficient still to do this:

```
Dim btn = DirectCast(myFlowLayoutPanel.Controls.
                                       FirstOrDefault(Function(b) b.Text = myText),
                     Button)
```

The difference would be negligible though and, if efficiency is your main concern, then you probably shouldn't be using LINQ at all.

Also note that `FirstOrDefault` is only appropriate if there may be zero, one or more matches.  Other methods are more appropriate in other cases:

`First`: There will always be at least one match but may be more then one.

`FirstOrDefault`: There may not be any matches and there may be more than one.

`Single`: There will always be exactly one match.

`SingleOrDefault`: There may be no matches but will never be more than one.

If you use one of the `OrDefault` methods then the result may be `Nothing` and you should ALWAYS test that result for `Nothing` before using it.

Comment: Great answer suggesting LINQ. How do `you find a control without a loop` was the question asked by the OP. Of course your suggestion doesn't directly have the `For` loop, but your suggestions are still loops and deviate from the question. The LINQ methods just hide it; the object is enumerated either by calling its `GetEnumerator` method directly or by using `For Each` in which `Controls.OfType` does. So how can we get the controls without a loop?